# Definite integral evaluation, how to solve it?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Hi guys I'm trying to solve the following integral that I've found in a paper:

$\int_{-l}^{l}$$\frac{\delta x}{((\frac{a-x}{r})^{2}+1)^{0.5}}$

The authors report the following result:

$sinh^{-1}(\frac{l-a}{r})+sinh^{-1}(\frac{l+a}{r})$

Any idea on how the steps required to obtain this result?

Comment: Let $\frac{a-x}{r}=\sinh t$.  We end up wanting $\int k\,dt$ for a certain constant!

Comment: General idea: sum of squares suggests a trigonometric substitution.  (In this case, when you are outside the range of the natural trig substitution, you can use a hyperbolic substitution instead.)

Comment: What do you mean by hyperbolic substitution? A change of variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

folowing the hint:
$$\int_{-l}^{l}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)^2+1}}\\
\sinh t=\frac{a-x}{r}\iff r\sinh t=a-x\\
r\cosh t dt=-dx\iff-r\cosh t=dx\\
-\sinh^2t+\cosh^2t=1\Rightarrow\cosh^2t=1+\sinh^2t\\
\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)^2+1}}=-r\int\frac{\cosh tdt}{\sqrt{\sinh^2t+1}}=-r\int\frac{\cosh tdt}{\sqrt{\cosh^2 t}}=\\
-r\int\frac{\cosh tdt}{\cosh t}=-r\int dt=-rt+C=-r~\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)+C\\
\int_{-l}^{l}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)^2+1}}=\left.-r~\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)\right|^{l}_{-l}=\\
-r~\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{a-l}{r}\right)+r~\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{a+l}{r}\right)$$

---

then lets proof that $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)^2+1}}=-r~\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)+C$

by fundamental theorem of calculus: $\int f(x)dx=F(x)\iff F'(x)=f(x)$

then

$\frac{d}{dx}\left[-r~\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)+C\right]=\frac{d}{dx}-r~\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)=-r\frac{d}{dx}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)$

using the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}\sinh^{-1}u=\frac{u'}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$, then

$-r\frac{d}{dx}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)=-r\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)^2}}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{a-x}{r}=-r\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)^2}}\cdot-\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{a-x}{r}\right)^2}}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however in this result the inverse hyperbolic functions are multiplied by $r$ while in the result that the authors report they are not...

Comment: @user3810266 cand's answer is correct. The result your authors reported is not.

Comment: Yeah i just recognized that there is a $\frac{1}{r}$ outsider the integral that i forgot to report